# Mixing strings and numbers with Excel Interop

Tags: f#, excel-interop

I'm using F# and Excel Interop. I'm doing something like:

```
workbook.Range("A1:A10").Value2 <- [| "foo"; "3"; "bar"; "6"; "8" |]
```

When I look at the resulting spreadsheet, it is storing the "3", "6", and "8" as strings instead of numbers. This means that formulas and such fail. Is there a way to make Excel convert strings to numbers where appropriate?

My current workaround is this:

```
workbook.Range("A1:A10").Value2 <- [| "foo" :> obj
                                      3 :> obj
                                      "bar" :> obj
                                      6 :> obj
                                      8 :> obj |]
```

It produces the desired effect, but it awkward. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let a : obj[] = [| "foo"; 3; ... |]
```

give the array a type annotation, and it will auto-upcast the elements.